# Database for an online store

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, relational-database, database-schema

I'm about to make an **online e-commerce** site for selling some **products like footwear,clothes etc**. but I'm unable to figure out how to set up the schema for that (tables and all). I'm doing it in **Ruby on Rails** with **Mysql** and I'm newbie in ROR.

Details are as follows:-

I have Different **categories** in **products** like **Footwear,Clothing,Accessories,Bags,etc** separate each for **Men and Women**.

The buyer selects the products and **add it to cart** and proceed to chekout. We just have a **cash on delivery type Payment system.** We wont be creating any user accounts.**No user accounts**

**How should I achieve that in Rails with all the controllers and the models?**
Should I make **separate table for each of the category**?
How should I categories the required Products in **Men and Women**?
Provide a complete schema and relationships table **the Rails way.**

Comment: can u just show the schema here?

Comment: What exactly you want? You want schema or structure or you are looking for the db design?

Comment: @Arihant Godha schema and db design.@Debadatt I haven't created any.

Comment: I use Northwind example to build a database relation from the scratch.Once it complete then we can convert to MySQL schema or other datatype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need `Categories` table and `Products` table. In products table you'll need `category_id:integer` field.

**Category.rb**

```
has_many :products
```

**Product.rb**

```
belongs_to :category
has_many :line_items
```

**Cart.rb**

```
has_many :line_items
```

**LineItem.rb** (table `line_items` with `product_id:integer` and `cart_id:integer`)

```
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
```

each time someone adds a `product` to `cart` it will create a `line_item` row with `product_id` and `cart_id` and you can also add quantity field to update if customer order more products of the same type.

For **Men** and **Women** types of products you could add a field in products table that will id id this product is for him or for her, `for_men: boolean, default:true`

**Product.rb**

```
belongs_to :category
has_many :line_items

scope :men, -> {where(for_men: true)}
scope :women, -> {where(for_men: false)}
```

and when if you call

```
 products = Product.all
 products.women
```

it will show you only products marked as women type, where `for_men` field is `false`.

In case when you extract products by category:

```
category = Category.find 1

category.products.women
```

will show you `products` for `women` of that `category`.

Comment: How do categories in Men and Women? Do I need to make separate table for each product? like separate table for footwear, clothing, etc?

Comment: You can add a column product type if you know there will be specific types like Men, Women,or children will be there.

Comment: looks promising. Will try this. :)

Comment: @ArihantGodha is right, if you'll have more types of products you can do it with product_type column.

Comment: @rmagnum2002 but my different categories would have different columns.like footwear and clothes will have a color column whereas the rest won't. how to manage that? should such columns be set to NIL where they don't exists?

Comment: @Mrudul_T so you just add color to products table and you'll display it in case the product is footwear or clothes. You can do all this later in development. I don't think you can overview here all the issues you might have in development process.

Answer (score 1):

The major tables that are required for an eCommerce store are.

```
    Product table
    Product type - type can define its type and category which it belongs to
    Cart - This table depends how you are dealing with cart items.
    Users - have an assosisation has many with oder
    Orders - have an assosiation with order status
    Order status
    Discount or Coupon Code
    Inquiry
```